# Using UserControl as ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, resourcedictionary

is it possible to use the Resources I defined in a `<UserControl.Resources>` in another UserControl, without using an extra file for a ResourceDictionary.

I have a UserControl "ViewCostumers" and in `<UserControl.Resources>` I define a DataTemplate with a ListView of all the customers.
Now I write a UserControl "ViewOverview" in which the same ListView shall appear. I would like keep the ListView in the file "ViewCostumer" if somehow possible.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
What I tried to do is that I keep the DataTempalte/ListView in the original file. Then I'd like to reference that file (which is a UserControl) from another file (like a resource dictionary, only ViewCostumer is a UserControl:

```
< ResourceDictionary> 
< ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>         
< ResourceDictionary Source="View/ViewCostumer.xaml" /> 
< /ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
< /ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: resources are referenced by their keys, so any place you want to use a resource just put the key in your code to ask for it ... there's no limit on the number of times you can use the same key.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to use the Resources I defined in a in another UserControl, without using an extra file for a ResourceDictionary.

No, it is not. After all, this is exactly what ResourceDictionaries are used for.

> I want to keep the Resources in the original file (which is a UserControl).

You can't and you shouldn't if you intend to use the resources in any other control than this particular `UserControl`. It simply makes no sense to define a resource in a `UserControl` if you intend to use this resource in any other control.

What you should do is to define the common resource in a `ResourceDictionary` that you then merge into both controls as suggested by @Ephraim.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the Resources to the Application scope.

Check out [Creating and Consuming Resource Dictionaries in WPF and Silverlight](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsldesigner/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight/) specifically the **Moving Resources to Application Scope**.

The idea is to move the resources into the Application.xaml so that in can be used throughout your entire application.

**Application.xaml**

```
<Application 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    x:Class="ResourceDictionaryDemo.App"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Application.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="formBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#460000FF" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <my:String x:Key="applicationTitle">Resource Dictionary Demo</my:String>
        <my:Double x:Key="applicationTitleFontSize">18</my:Double>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="applicationTitleForeground">Yellow</SolidColorBrush>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: That's exactly not what I want. I want to keep the Resources in the original file (which is a UserControl)

Comment: The way I understood your question is that you don't want to create an extra file. Anyway, this is an option because the scope of your `Resources` is only on the user control it was placed in thus it cannot be shared.

Comment: What I really wish would work is that I keep the DataTempalte/ListView in the original file. Then I'd like to reference that file (wich is a UserControl)  from another file (like
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="View/ViewCostumer.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>